# file_get_contents not working with blockchain api

Tags: php, file-get-contents, html-encode

This is the code I have

```
<?php
include("connect.php");
$bc = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM `blockchain`");
$bc->execute();
$bcs = $bc->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$type = $_REQUEST['type'];

$price = $_REQUEST['amount'];

$uid = $_REQUEST['uid'];

$secret = $bcs['apikey'];

$my_address = $bcs['badd'];

$my_callback_url = 'http://www.imusicsong.com/api/bcp.php?secret='.$secret;

$root_url = 'https://blockchain.info/api/receive';

$parameters = 'method=create&address=' . $my_address .'&callback='. urlencode($my_callback_url);

$response = file_get_contents($root_url . '?' . $parameters);

$object = json_decode($response);

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `orders` (`uid`, `processor`, `type`, `date`, `price`) VALUES (:uid, 'bitcoin', :type, '".date("Y-m-d")."', :price)");
$stmt->execute(array(":uid" => $uid, ":type" => $type, ":price" => $price));

echo 'Send Payment in the amount of '.$price.' BTC To Bitcoin Address : ' . $object->input_address;
?>
```

Which is derived from their own code for the api located here https://blockchain.info/api/api_receive

Everything is set up correctly but I get the following error

```
Warning: file_get_contents(https://blockchain.info/api/receive?method=create&amp;address=yourbitcoinaddress&amp;callback=http://www.imusicsong.com/api/bcp.php?secret=replacewithbcapi): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error in C:\wamp\www\music\bc.php on line 23
```

if I copy and paste that url into my browser it does load but it gives me the error `Error You Must Provide a Destination Address`

If I change all of the `&amp;` back to just `&` in that link then it loads the `json response`

```
{"callback_url":"http:\/\/www.imusicsong.com\/api\/bcp.php?secret=replacewithbcapi","input_address":"16uEPhaC5B5v6xLKem4hDoQRE11yZ4nEc4","destination":"1McVCZZrUgtkrUMkqfTF8kaaSSQBg54Fkd","fee_percent":0}
```

So not only do I not know why it is giving me that error, even it it wasn't throwing that error the fact that is passes the url with `&amp;` instead of `&` is going to cause their system to not pass the proper response.

So I need to identify how to fix both problems.

1.) Why is `file_get_contents` not opening the url

2.) How can I make `file_get_contents` not change `&` into `&amp;`

Comment: At the very least, `$parameters` should be [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/urlencode)ed before making the request.  It probably works in the browser because it parses the URL and encodes it for you, unlike PHP.

Comment: I added the `urlencode()` it was already there but I copied the above code before I added it but it is there

Comment: In that case, edit the code in the question so we know exactly what you're working with.

Comment: Ok, I have updated it

Comment: Do you have `OpenSSL` enabled?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy according to `phpinfo() OpenSSL` is enabled.

Comment: Is `$my_address` properly formatted?  Try `urlencode`ing that as well.  I tested with the API and get no errors with similar code but if I add a character to the address that needs to be urlencoded I get a 500 internal server error.